# How does an atheist begin study of the Qu'ran?

Tags: quran, arabic

I am Safal. I was born into a Hindu background, and when I wanted to drop my religion and become an atheist, my dad told me to learn more about Hinduism first. I learned a little bit of Sanskrit, and I can now read some passages of the Ṛgveda. I am now obsessed with finding out more about the religions of the world, and ancient languages as well. For these reasons, I would like to begin learning Classical Arabic. What are some good ways to start? For now, I am using Khaild Zaheer's series on Quranic (Classical) Arabic. Thanks for any answers!

Comment: There is a stackexchange site on classical arabic : https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105382/arabic-language